# Формы django

Tags: python, forms, django

Есть такие модели:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    kind = models.ForeignKey(Kind, verbose_name="Тип предмета")
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class BuildingRequiredItem(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey('Building', related_name="fk_required_items")
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Building(Item):
    width = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()    
    required_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item,
        through=BuildingRequiredItem,
        related_name='buildings_required', blank=True, null=True)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать следующую штуку: хочу, чтобы при редактировании параметров здания можно было добавлять, удалять, редактировать список требуемых предметов для этого здания (обратите внимание на through, есть доп. поле - кол-во). Подозреваю, что тут как-то можно использовать inline formset-ы, но что-то не получается.

Comment: А что вы попробовали, что у вас не получается? `InlineModelAdmin` пробовали?

Comment: InlineModelAdmin - то, что нужно. А как его использовать в своем приложении, не в админке?

Answer (score 1):

Всё таки, думаю, смотрите в сторону [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.inlineformset_factory)

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
building = Building.objects.get(pk=1)
BuildingRequiredItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Building, BuildingRequiredItem, 
    fields=('item', 'count'), extra=3)
BuildingRequiredItemFormSet(instance=building)
```

В этом случае нужно будет выбирать Item и указывать количество. Чтобы избежать возможного дублирования Айтемов для одного Здания, добавьте [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together) в BuildingRequiredItem.Meta

Если же хотите, чтобы выводились все Item-ы и нужно было только заполнять поле count, то выход примерно такой. Боюсь накидано на коленках и нужно поискать ошибки и оптимизировать.

```
class BuildingRequiredItemForm(forms.Form):
    building_pk = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    item_pk = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    count = forms.IntegerField()

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        bqi, created = BuildingRequiredItem.objects.get_or_create(
            building__id=data['building_pk'],
            item__id=data['item_pk'],
            )
        bqi.count = data['count']

        bqi.save()
        if bqi.count == 0:
            bqi.delete()

BuildingRequiredItemFormset = formset_factory(BuildingRequiredItemForm, extra=0)



building = Building.objects.get(pk=1)
items = Item.objects.all()
instance = []
for item in items:
    buildingrequireditem = building.buildingrequireditem_set.filter(item=item)
    if buildingrequireditem:
        count = buildingrequireditem[0].count
    else:
        count = 0

    instance.append({
        'building_pk': building.pk,
        'item_pk': item.pk,
        'count': count})
```

Как видите, в форме item_pk. По нему нужно будет перед полем count вывести имя item-а

Answer (score -1):

Изучите функционал различных библиотек для Django работающих с формами. Вы можете это сделать обычным запросом в google.com. И в случае этого запроса, не конкретизируйте проблему и задачу, которая должна выполнять эта библиотека, следует изучить разные библиотеки и самостоятельно понять их преимущества, это будет чрезвычайно полезно.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/761465)

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).